# Force template to small screen (responsive)

Tags: jquery, css, jstree

I'm looking for a solution for the good plugin jsTree (http://www.jstree.com/).

Demo page : http://www.jstree.com/demo/

What happen is that if we look at the plugin on small devices, the default template change when width is smaller than approximately `760px` (looks like it's responsive). What I'm trying to do, is to force template to allways show as the small "style" and not the normal tree style.

Does someone allready tried to achieve this ? After looking into the default template css I've found a `@media (max-width:768px){}` that is declared for the responsive template. I've tried to change values and to force plugin to use responsive style, but it's not displaying like the small style.

Here is some of the code I've tried (without any success) :

```
$.jstree.defaults.core.themes.variant = 'responsive';
    $('#jstree').jstree({
        core:{
            themes:{
                variant:'responsive'
            }
        },
        themes:{
            set_theme_variant:'responsive',
            variant:'responsive'
        }
}).jstree('set_theme_variant','responsive');
```

Thank you for your help, best regards.

Ruben

Answer (score 0):

Finally find out how to force it to small devices. Actually I though that max-width was the default template max-width. In reality, you have to put for example @media (max-width:2500px){} (for example) to allways show the small template.